# Multipart Request not processed by the Multipart Resolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, csrf, multipartform-data

I have recently made a few changes to my spring application by adding csrf support to it. For that I also had to change the way multipart requests were previously handled.

To make sure multipart requests get through properly I placed the `org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter` before `org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy` in `web.xml`

Though it is working fine for most of the request but some requests are not receiving any request parameter at the controller level. I debugged a little and found that at this code

```
HttpServletRequest processedRequest = request;
    if (multipartResolver.isMultipart(processedRequest)) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Resolving multipart request [" + processedRequest.getRequestURI() +
                    "] with MultipartFilter");
        }
        processedRequest = multipartResolver.resolveMultipart(processedRequest);
    }
    else {
        // A regular request...
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Request [" + processedRequest.getRequestURI() + "] is not a multipart request");
        }
    }
```

inside the `MultipartFilter` is not processing my request as multipart. The request goes to the else part when the `multipartResolver.isMultipart(processedRequest)` check is made.

The form present inside the `JSP` has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` parameter.

```
<form:form modelAttribute="configVO" name="ConfigForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="${contextPath}/project/urlConfig">
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <div class="urldivSales">
            <div class="main-subdiv-urls-msa">
                <div class="leftlable">
                    <span>Website Name</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-subdiv-urls-msa">
                <div class="leftlable">
                    <span>Request URL</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-subdiv-urls-msa">
                <div class="leftlable">
                    <span>Response URL</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-subdiv-urls-msa">
                <div class="leftlable">
                    <span>Image Name</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-subdiv-urls-msa">
                <div class="leftlable">
                    <span>Image File</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="main-subdiv-urls-msa">
                <div class="rightbox">
                    <div id='url'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-subdiv-urls-msa">
                <div class="rightbox">
                    <div id='req'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-subdiv-urls-msa">
                <div class="rightbox">
                    <div id='res'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-subdiv-urls-msa">
                <div class="rightbox">
                    <div id='image'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-subdiv-urls-msa">
                <div class="rightbox">
                    <div id='imageFile'></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form3buttons">
                <input type="button" name="button" id="save" value="Save" onclick="validateForm();" /> 
                <input type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

**javascript validation method**

```
function validateForm() {
$('#save').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
var isValid = false;
var noOfRows = '${num}';
var webSiteArray = new Array(); 
var imageNameArray = new Array();   
for(var i=0; i<noOfRows; i++) {
    var web = "web"+i;
    var req = "req"+i;
    var res = "res"+i;
    var image = "image"+i;

    var webSiteUrl =  document.getElementById(web).value;
    var imageNameValue =  document.getElementById(image).value;
    webSiteArray[i]= webSiteUrl;
    imageNameArray[i]= imageNameValue;
    var newReqUrl = document.getElementById(req).value;
    var newResUrl = document.getElementById(res).value;
    isValid = checkParm(webSiteUrl,newReqUrl,newResUrl);
    if (!isValid) {
       $('#save').removeAttr("disabled");
       break;   
    }
}

if (isValid) {
    if (checkValueisEqual(webSiteArray, imageNameArray)) {
      var contextPath = '${contextPath}'+'/project/urlConfig';
      document.forms[0].action= contextPath;
      document.forms[0].submit();
    }
}
```

}

**filter mappings in web.xml**

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The only special thing present here is that the `<input type="file">` elements are added on the fly using the javascript.

Am I missing something here... One last thing to note - before adding the csrf support the code was running fine and the request parameters were received at controller end

Comment: And are you actually submitting THAT form or are you also submitting it through javascript, happily ignoring all the settings in the form? Also placing the filter before the other doesn't guarantee anything, the import part is the `filter-mapping` elements not the `filter` elements. The order of the `filter-mapping` is important!

Comment: @M.Deinum the form is being submit through javascript. I have edited the post and added the method in use

Comment: add your web.xml as well, at least the filter part.

Comment: added the filter mappings

Comment: One thing I don't get is why are you setting the action url again? It is already on the form. How are you adding the input elements?

Comment: @M.Deinum It is some legacy code, even I am not sure why they have done it ... but with your asking about the submit part I guess I am near to solving this one .. will post the resolution if it pays off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks M.Deinum for asking how the request is being submit.

Well I managed to pull it off by changing the way the form is being submit.

Here's the change
**javascript function for validation**

```
function validateForm() {
$('#save').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
var isValid = false;
var noOfRows = '${num}';
var webSiteArray = new Array();
var imageNameArray = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<noOfRows; i++) {
    var web = "web"+i;
    var req = "req"+i;
    var res = "res"+i;
    var image = "image"+i;

    var webSiteUrl =  document.getElementById(web).value;
    var imageNameValue =  document.getElementById(image).value;
    webSiteArray[i]= webSiteUrl;
    imageNameArray[i]= imageNameValue;
    var newReqUrl = document.getElementById(req).value;
    var newResUrl = document.getElementById(res).value;
    isValid = checkParm(webSiteUrl,newReqUrl,newResUrl);
    if (!isValid) {
       $('#save').removeAttr("disabled");
       return false;
    }
}

if (isValid) {
    if (checkValueisEqual(webSiteArray, imageNameArray)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
} }
```

**form changes**

```
<form:form modelAttribute="configVO" name="ConfigForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="${contextPath}/project/urlConfig" onsubmit = "return validateForm();">
<input type="submit" name="button" id="save" value="Save" />
```